# What is the proper term for a huge chisel-like tool used for building log cabins?

Tags: hand-tools

Cabin builders use this tool for about the same purpose as a regular chisel. It is about 4" wide, 1 1/2 foot long, and with a 1 1/2-2 foot long handle. What do you call it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be talking about a slick:

[image: picture of slick]

This is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slick_(tool)) has to say:

> A slick is a large chisel, characterized by a wide (2-4 inches, 5–10
> cm), heavy blade, and a long, frequently slender, socketed handle. The
> combined blade and handle can reach two feet (60 cm) in length. The
> blade of a slick is slightly curved lengthwise, and/or the handle
> socket is cranked upward, such that the handle and socket clear the
> surface of the work when the edge is touching. This distinguishes the
> slick from the similarly-sized, short-handled millwright's chisel.

Comment: Correct...though it's more of a **timberframing** than **log cabin** tool, IME.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're describing an ADZE which is a tool used to shape logs:

[Adze](https://www.loghomestore.com/product/barr-flat-ship-carpenter-hewing-adze/)

Comment: jwh20, adze is an ax, and I mean a real chisel on steroids.